# Injecting Interface to Background Service

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to inject interface to a service that runs with `timer` but I am getting an error. I believe it has to do with my `ConfigureServices` class. I do not have issue when injecting the interface to other controllers that inherit from `ControllerBase`. Im am using .NET6 WebApi.

I am getting error in terminal

`Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: API.Services.AddressCheck': Cannot consume scoped service 'API.Interfaces.IInvoiceRepository' from singleton 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService'.) ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: API.Services.AddressCheck': Cannot consume scoped service 'API.Interfaces.IInvoiceRepository' from singleton 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService'.`

AddressCheck Service

```
namespace API.Services
{
    public class AddressCheck : BackgroundService
    {

        private readonly PeriodicTimer _timer = new(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5000));
        public ILogger<AddressCheck> Logger { get; }
        private IInvoiceRepository _invoiceRepository;

        public AddressCheck(ILogger<AddressCheck> logger, IInvoiceRepository invoiceRepository)
        {
            _invoiceRepository = invoiceRepository;
            this.Logger = logger;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (await _timer.WaitForNextTickAsync(stoppingToken) && !stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
               
                    {
                        await CheckList();
                    }
                
            }
        }

        public async Task CheckList()
        {

            var x = _invoiceRepository.GetListofAddress();
        }
```

startup class

```
 services.AddHostedService<AddressCheck>();
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/scoped-service

Comment: The issue is your different lifetimes. IInvoiceRepository is scoped, while IHostedService is singleton. Injecting IInvoiceRepository into IHostedService would basically give you a single instance of IInvoiceRepository for lifetime of service.

Comment: One option is to inject your container into your BackgroundService, and then resolve your object graph per invocation of `CheckList()`